# Añadir columnas de agregación, a una consulta que no tiene group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by, tsql

tengo esta select que recupera una serie de datos:

```
select 
  G.CTI_IdTransaction, L.PeticionId,  Tipo, ValorTipo, SubTipo, ValorSubTipo, Unidades 
  , G.GestionInicio FechaLlamda, G.UserName Agente, CierreN1, CierreN2, Observacion_OUT, Descripcion
  , CTI_TelefonoLlamado, CTI_TelefonoLlamante
  from vw_ListasTipificaciones L
  inner join vw_Gestiones G on G.PeticionId = L.PeticionId
  inner join DB2.dbo.vwTransaccionesTotal vt ON vt.idTransaccion=G.CTI_IdTransaction
```

Quiero añadir a la consulta, columnas de agregación, manteniendo las que ya están pero me aparece el error que no están añadidas al GROUP BY:

```
 select 
  G.CTI_IdTransaction, L.PeticionId,  Tipo, ValorTipo, SubTipo, ValorSubTipo, Unidades 
  , G.GestionInicio FechaLlamda, G.UserName Agente, CierreN1, CierreN2, Observacion_OUT, Descripcion
  , CTI_TelefonoLlamado, CTI_TelefonoLlamante,
  --Tiempo medio de conversación
    Round(Avg(Case When (vct.ncanal = 0 And vct.nSentido = 1 And vct.idAgente > 0 And vct.tEstablecimiento Is Not Null) 
    Then DateDiff(SECOND, vct.tEstablecimiento, vct.tFinal) Else Null End),0) As TMEDIO_CONVERSACION,
    --Tiempo Total de Gestion
    Sum(Case When (vct.ncanal = 0 And vct.nSentido = 1 And vct.idAgente > 0 And vct.tEstablecimiento Is Not Null) 
    then DateDiff(SECOND, vct.tInicio, vct.tFinal) Else Null End) As TTOTAL_GESTION,
    --Tiempo medio de espera antes de ser atendido
    Round(Avg(Case When (vct.ncanal = 0 And vct.nSentido = 1 And vct.idAgente > 0 And vct.tEstablecimiento Is Not Null)  
    Then (DateDiff(SECOND, vct.tInicio, vct.tEstablecimiento) + vt.nTQ) Else Null End),0) As TMEDIO_ESPERA
  from vw_ListasTipificaciones L
  inner join vw_Gestiones G on G.PeticionId = L.PeticionId
  inner join DB2.dbovwTransaccionesTotal vt ON vt.idTransaccion=G.CTI_IdTransaction
  Left Join DB2.dbo.vwContactosTotal vct On vt.idTransaccion  = vct.idTransaccion 
  Group By Format(vct.tFinal, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Alguna sugerencia ? uso de subconsultas o CTE ?

Comment: Es simple, si pones un `group by` tienes que repetir en este todas las columnas del `select`, menos claro las que tienen funciones de agregación.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No hay otra opción entonces, hay que poner todas las columnas en el group by ( no hay implicaciones al poner muchas columnas?). Entiendo que es una buena práctica todas las columnas (que no sean de agregación) en el group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La estructura básica de una consulta de agregación es:

```sql
select   columna1
       , columna2
       , ...
       , columnan
       , funcion_agregacion1(columna)
       , funcion_agregacion2(columna)
       , ...
       , funcion_agregacionn(columna)
  from tabla1
       join tabla2
       ...
       join tablan
 group by   columna1
          , columna2
          , ...
          , columnan
```

Puedes observar que **todas** las columnas que no forman parte de una función de agregación **deben** aparecer en la cláusula ***group by***.

`columna1`  y similares pueden ser expresiones, incluyendo llamadas a funciones.

Así, de entrada, no hace falta usar CTE's ni otras estructuras, sino agregar las columnas que actualmente no son parte de una función de agregación a la cláusula group by, o bien a alguna función de agregación.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente consulta debiera ejecutarse si dar el mismo error que estás observando:

```sql
select   G.CTI_IdTransaction
       , L.PeticionId
       , Tipo
       , ValorTipo
       , SubTipo
       , ValorSubTipo
       , Unidades 
       , G.GestionInicio FechaLlamda
       , G.UserName Agente
       , CierreN1
       , CierreN2
       , Observacion_OUT
       , Descripcion
       , CTI_TelefonoLlamado
       , CTI_TelefonoLlamante
       , round(avg(case 
                     when vct.ncanal = 0 
                      and vct.nSentido = 1 
                      and vct.idAgente > 0 
                      and vct.tEstablecimiento is not null 
                     then datediff(second, vct.tEstablecimiento, vct.tFinal) 
                   end
                  ), 0
              ) as TMEDIO_CONVERSACION
       , sum(case 
               when vct.ncanal = 0 
                and vct.nSentido = 1 
                and vct.idAgente > 0 
                and vct.tEstablecimiento is not null 
               then datediff(second, vct.tInicio, vct.tFinal) 
             end
            ) As TTOTAL_GESTION
      , round(avg(case 
                    when vct.ncanal = 0 
                     and vct.nSentido = 1 
                     and vct.idAgente > 0 
                     and vct.tEstablecimiento is not null 
                    then (datediff(second, vct.tInicio, vct.tEstablecimiento) + vt.nTQ) 
                  end
                 ), 0
             ) As TMEDIO_ESPERA
  from vw_ListasTipificaciones L
       inner join vw_Gestiones G on G.PeticionId = L.PeticionId
       inner join DB2.dbovwTransaccionesTotal vt ON vt.idTransaccion=G.CTI_IdTransaction
       left join DB2.dbo.vwContactosTotal vct On vt.idTransaccion  = vct.idTransaccion 
 group by  G.CTI_IdTransaction
         , L.PeticionId
         , Tipo
         , ValorTipo
         , SubTipo
         , ValorSubTipo
         , Unidades 
         , G.GestionInicio FechaLlamda
         , G.UserName Agente
         , CierreN1
         , CierreN2
         , Observacion_OUT
         , Descripcion
         , CTI_TelefonoLlamado
         , CTI_TelefonoLlamante
```

**Advertencia**: Dado que hay columnas sin calificar y el `from` tiene una tabla más, podría dar otros errores, pero no el mismo.

Si no te da el resultado que esperas, y que no has incluido en la pregunta, con lo que te he explicado, debieras poder adaptarla a tus necesidades.

Comment: grz! Destalles: en el group by, no utilizar alias para campos. Ej: solo G.GestionInicio. Y en mi caso, hay que indicar un ORDER BY adecuado.

Comment: *todas las columnas que no forman parte de una función de agregación deben aparecer en la cláusula group by* , en el mismo orden ??

Comment: No es necesario que aparezcan en el mismo orden.